# How to reset key values in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3, l3keys

In the MWE below, how can I reset the value of the `title` key, assigned to `\l__lecture_title_tl`, so that the third instance of `\lecture` doesn't print `A title`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { lecture-notes } {
  title .tl_set:N = \l__lecture_title_tl,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \lecture }{ O{} }{
  \keys_set:nn { lecture-notes } { #1 }

  \tl_set:Nn \l__section_title_tl {
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__lecture_title_tl { \l__lecture_title_tl }
  }

  \section{\l__section_title_tl}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lecture
\lipsum[1]

\lecture[title={A title}]
\lipsum[2]

\lecture % <-- this still prints 'A title'
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I enclose the definition of the `\lecture` command in `\group_begin: ... \group_end:`, the vertical spacing between the sections is affected, and the following text is indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your definition of `\lecture`, you get `\keys_set:nn { lecture-notes } {}` when the optional argument is not used, so naturally no keys are reset. Instead, you want to pass `title={}`. So you need `\NewDocumentCommand{ \lecture }{ O{title={}} }{...`.